# Type error after adding @types/react-select

Tags: typescript, react-select

After yarn add `@types/react-select`
I am trying to run my project it is showing the following error though it was working earlier, the problem seems to happen today.

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-select/src/components/indicators.d.ts,Generic type 'ReactElement<P>' requires 1 type argument(s)
```

In package.json I have :

```
"react": "^16.4.0",
"react-dom": "^16.4.0",
"@types/react": "^16.3.16",
"@types/react-select": "^3.0.2",
```

Comment: please add the code that uses `react-select`

Comment: You may have multiple versions of `@types/react` installed. The type parameter is optional in the current version. This is a transitive dependency issue.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, if i dont add @types/react-select, its giving error for my typescript. and if react is 16.4 should type/react also be 16.4?

Comment: @Peter, i am just installing it and it is giving error before adding any code

Comment: @Pragati I was not saying that you do not need `@types/react-select`. You need it. Yes, you `@types/react` and `react` version should match.